# "Locally euclidean" doesn't mean "locally flat"

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, spherical-geometry

I'm considering a topological manifold $M$ (e.g. a 2-sphere).

Every point of $M$ (in the 2-sphere case, the whole sphere excluding the pole) is homeomorphic to an open interval of $\mathbb R^N$ (for the sphere, $\mathbb R^2$). This allows to define charts.

However, on so much contributions over the web, the stressed feature is the fact that just a *very* small neighborhood of a point $p \subset M$ "looks like" a flat portion of space (the usual example from cartography, see e.g. the first answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933137/why-the-surface-of-the-sphere-is-not-a-euclidean-space) discussion), which seems me misleading.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Locally means some neighborhood, which can be small but doesn’t have to be. Topological manifolds don’t have a notion of curvature, or for that matter a notion of size.

Comment: I know, thank you. So why the importance of the apparent "flatness" of a small neighborhood is so stressed?

Comment: @LoScrondo: Because most people care about the sphere not just as a topological manifold, but as a Riemannian manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of 'looking flat' is weaker than what we intuitively think it is. In the example of cartography, the time when we get into trouble is when we try to map the *whole* earth at once. 'Small' maps where at least one point is taken away are contorted, but we understand what they mean. Most importantly, we can jump between such maps (turning the page in an atlas) in a homeomorphic fashion.

When you are trying to convince people of this with differential manofolds, it's much easier to talk about very small map snippets, because at that scale the then differentiable functions are almost identity maps. It not only can be mapped to a flat surface, it already 'looks flat'.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, I think I've understood. Just to check, could you rephrase this sentence, " 'Small' maps where at least one point is taken away are contorted, but we understand what they mean"?

Comment: By 'small' I just want to point out that a map from the 2-sphere less a point to the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 'local enough' even though it intuitively seems not to be.

Comment: We 'know what they mean' in that we can measure distances and angles on the sphere (less a point) by looking at the map on the plane. We just need to adjust our readings (and what we mean by straight lines) according to the appropriate function, to compensate for curvature. The results will agree with those from another such map. As celtschk commented, this last elaboration assumes the existence of a metric. If we only have a topological manifold, comparing them is not really defined in other ways than that the transition maps should be homomorphisms.