# A Question About Homeomorphisms And Geography

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that we can not make a perfect 2-dimensional map of the earth, to achieve this I have figured out that I must prove there is not a homeomorphism from the surface of a sphere to the 2-dimensional plane, but how can I prove this?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sphere and the plane are not homeomorphic to each other; the sphere is compact, the plane isn't.
Actually, the question has been answered more generally:

[Why the surface of the sphere is not a Euclidean space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933137/why-the-surface-of-the-sphere-is-not-a-euclidean-space)